# SSIS Conditional Split does not contains part of a string

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have this table in my SQL Server:

```
ID    inn_name 
--------------------------------------
1     VITAMIN C(ASCORBIC ACID) + ZINC
2     Phosphore
3     AMOX + ACID + VITAMIN D
4     Sirop
```

In SSIS, I want to use conditional split to redirect all the names without 'VITAMIN' (ID 2 and ID 4)

So I'm trying to use this function to redirect the name without 'Vitamin' in conditional split.

```
FINDSTRING (inn_name, "VITAMIN", 1) != 1
```

[image: Conditional Split SSIS]

I tried many things but its still not redirect them. How could I fix this? Does this redirect only if the full row contains VITAMIN?

Comment: Please add one more screen shot to your question: a Data Viewer on the SSIS pipeline just before the Conditional Split Task.

Comment: Also, I would suggest to modify the SSIS expression as follows: `FINDSTRING (UPPER(inn_name), "VITAMIN", 1) != 1`

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to check if it is >0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/findstring-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15

```
FINDSTRING (inn_name, "VITAMIN", 1) > 0
```